# IRForTarget error in Xcode 4.6 LLDB

Tags: xcode, lldb, xcode4.6

Since upgrading to the Xcode 4.6 final, I oftentimes see this in LLDB:

```
(lldb) po [0x12eaf7a0 description]
Error [IRForTarget]: Call to a symbol-only function 'objc_msgSend' that is not present in the target
error: warning: receiver type 'int' is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id'
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target
```

I can verify that `0x12eaf7a0` is a valid object by adding it as an expression in the left pane. I can even successfully display the description for it by using the "Print Description" context menu.

Any ideas (except from switching back to GDB)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to cast your address to id, e.g.

```
(lldb) po [(id)0x12eaf7a0 description]
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn't help. I assume it's related to the specific backtrace (Open GL rendering) I was in when arbitrarily pausing the app.

Comment: Interesting.  This is with Xcode 4.6?  I'd recommend filing a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/ on lldb - especially if you can narrow it down to a small reproduction case.  This is not expected behavior.